# Uploading Large Text File Into A DB2 CLOB Field

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, blob, clob

Alrighty, I've been banging my head against the wall on this one for a while, so here it goes...

I'm currently writing a Java (1.5) program that can upload very large (200MB+) text files to a DB2 CLOB Column, but have been running into a few issues.

During my research, several code examples suggested that I use the PreparedStatement method `setCharacterStream()` to upload data to the CLOB Field, giving me something like this:

```
 PreparedStatement preparedStatement =  
      connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BOOKCOVERS VALUES(?,?)"); 
File imageFile = new File("c:\\redbookcover.jpg"); 
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(imageFile); 
preparedStatement.setString(1," 0738425826"); 
preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(2,inputStream,(int)(imageFile.length())); 
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

This is fine, except for the fact that the `setCharacterStream()` method requires a LENGTH value, specifying the number of characters to write to the field.  With this in mind, this limits the number of characters that can be written to CLOB Field to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Doing a little math, this will limit the size of the text file that I can upload to 524288 bytes, or about half of a Megabyte.  Since a CLOB field can store up to 2GB of data, I'm a bit confused.

I see that in Java 1.6 the PreparedStatement's `setCharacterStream()` method has been modified to not require a length, and will read until end-of-file is encountered.  Unfortunately, I'm required to use Java 1.5, so this is not a valid option.

In one last bit of research, I read that Java 1.5's PreparedStatement has similar functionality, where the Javadoc is claiming:

> "...it may be more practical to send
>   it via a java.io.Reader object. The
>   data will be read from the stream as
>   needed until end-of-file is reached."

If this exists, why does the `setCharacterStream()` method still require a length parameter?  What would you pass in for the length parameter to use this functionality?  Is there a better way to do this that I'm missing?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you think Integer.MAX_VALUE is 524288?  It's 2GB-1 (2^32-1)

Comment: I think your math is a little off.  Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses!  Woops, not sure what went wrong with my logic there....  Either way, I was hoping that some sort of streaming solution would have been available.  This concept seems to be more prevalent in the Oracle DB examples, so I thought something similar would exist for DB2.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the 1.5 spec for `setCharacterStream` is ambiguous about whether it reads to end-of-file or until length is reached.

> Sets the designated parameter to the
>   given Reader  object, which is the
>   given number of characters long. When
>   a very large UNICODE value is input to
>   a LONGVARCHAR  parameter, it may be
>   more practical to send it via a
>   java.io.Reader object. The data will
>   be read from the stream as needed
>   until end-of-file is reached. The JDBC
>   driver will do any necessary
>   conversion from UNICODE to the
>   database char format.

It may work like you want if you pass `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as the length parameter.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I tried specifying Integer.MAX_VALUE, but ended up getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException.  The same happened when I used -1 and 0 just didn't write anything.  These are the only values I'd imagine could be used to signal to read the buffer until it's empty...